# Como remover atributos de filhos de um elemento pai javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Bom o problema era o seguinte, no código tinha um botão que invocava uma função que gerava um Excel de uma determinada tabela, porem não estava sendo gerado o arquivo Excel, vinha tudo em branco e bugado, analisando identifiquei que o script da função na hora de interpretar a tabela para Excel só entendia as tags html e devido ter estilos em linha não era gerado corretamente.

Então eu preciso retirar todos os estilos em linha gerados por uma validação no backend PHP, sem modificar a visualização da tabela para o usuário.

segue o código:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="exportExcel">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Colaborador</th>
            <th>Centro de custo</th>
            <th>Dias restantes</th>
            <th>Referente ao período</th>
            <th>Data limite CLT</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background:#e17055; color:#fff;">Zezinho</td>
            <td style="background:#e17055; color:#fff;">xxxxxx</td>
            <td style="background:#e17055; color:#fff;">x</td>
            <td style="background:#e17055; color:#fff;">dd/mm/yyyy a dd/mm/yyyy</td>
            <td style="background:#e17055; color:#fff;">dd/mm/yyyy</td>
            <td style="background:#e17055; color:#fff;">vencido</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background:#e17055; color:#fff;">Joãozinho</td>
            <td style="background:#e17055; color:#fff;">xxxxxxxxx</td>
            <td style="background:#e17055; color:#fff;">x</td>
            <td style="background:#e17055; color:#fff;">dd/mm/yyyy a dd/mm/yyyy</td>
            <td style="background:#e17055; color:#fff;">dd/mm/yyyy</td>
            <td style="background:#e17055; color:#fff;">vencido</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background:#e17055; color:#fff;">Mariazinha</td>
            <td style="background:#e17055; color:#fff;">xxxxxxxxxx</td>
            <td style="background:#e17055; color:#fff;">x</td>
            <td style="background:#e17055; color:#fff;">dd/mm/yyyy a dd/mm/yyyy</td>
            <td style="background:#e17055; color:#fff;">dd/mm/yyyy</td>
            <td style="background:#e17055; color:#fff;">vencido</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Cristian! É bacana que separe a pergunta e resposta.

Comment: @BrewertonSantos Poderia me mostrar um exemplo prático para que eu arrume aqui. Desde já agradeço! aguardo seu retorno.

Comment: Veja perguntas já respondidas na comunidade. Sua questão está bem elaborada. Eu diria (apenas como sugestão mesmo) para cortar a parte da resposta e adicionar como resposta no campo abaixo da sua pergunta.

Comment: @BrewertonSantos Entendi vou fazer isso, Obrigado pela dica de ouro!

Comment: Separar em pergunta e resposta já ajuda bastante, mas é importante [edit] e explicar melhor a questão (até pelo fato de que se a solução é o que está na resposta, a pergunta seria "como remover um atributo", não se limita a estilos) - e daria para converter o código em um [mcve], para que seja mais abrangente para um público amplo (e para dar um contexto onde isso seria necessário, pois no dia-a-dia não é muito normal ter que usar um JS para remover um estilo, que normalmente seria removido na origem, não depois) - na forma em que se encontra pode dar a entender que é trivial resolver assim.

Comment: @Bacco Obrigado pelo feedback, esta melhor formulado a pergunta agora na sua opinião ?

Comment: O problema é que com essa descrição, o caso seria de alterar o PHP que gera, e não tirar com JS depois. de qq forma, ao editar a pergunta entra numa revisão (e vai para o topo da home) e a comunidade pode votar pela reabertura ou não, isso é automático.

Comment: @Bacco ai que está eu não posso alterar na raiz, pois altera a visualização da tabela para o cliente, por isso fiz com JS na hora de gerar o Excel eu retiro todos os estilos aplicados em linha.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Como remover o atributo style dos filhos da table.

```
<script>
    const pai = document.getElementById('exportExcel')
    const filhos = pai.querySelectorAll('td')
    
    filhos.forEach(filho => {
        filho.removeAttribute('style')
    });
</script>
```

Implementei esse script dentro da função que gerava o Excel e funcionou.

Comment: Beleza! Parabéns, agora para saberem que esta resposta te atendeu (o óbvio precisa ser dito). Marca ela como resposta.

Comment: @BrewertonSantos Como ele respondeu à própria pergunta, o sistema só deixa marcar a resposta depois de algumas horas (não lembro exatamente quantas).

Comment: @hkotsubo dois dias, valeu galera tmj!

Comment: Então tudo certo!